# How to model directories and files using schema.org types with JSON-LD syntax?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I'm trying to model the concept of folders (or directories) and files.  Folders can contain files, or other folders (arbitrary nested recursive structure, like on your typical filesystem). I would ideally like to start with a schema.org context and base type, and extend that to represent these entities.  For various reasons, I am also interested in using JSON-LD as the format.

After some research and looking into examples, it seems like using a
base of http://schema.org/CreativeWork, along with [`additionalType`](https://schema.org/additionalType) in conjunction with productontology.org is a relatively straightforward
way to express this.  But is this a *good* way to express these concepts?  I am open to using just about anything else, in place of an entry from  productontology.org, as the `additionalType`, particularly if it allows me to express more meaningful properties than simply using those from `CreativeWork`.

Proposed folder example ([playground link](http://tinyurl.com/onyp3jn)):

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "@id": "http://my-site.com/folder/1",
  "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/doc/Directory_(computing)",
  "name": "My Folder",
  "url": "http://my-site.com/folder/1"
}
```

Proposed file example ([playground link](http://tinyurl.com/nanr9ga)):

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org/",
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "@id": "http://my-site.com/file/2",
  "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/doc/Computer_file",
  "name": "My File",
  "isPartOf": {
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "CreativeWork",
    "@id": "http://my-site.com/folder/1",
    "additionalType": "http://www.productontology.org/doc/Directory_(computing)",
    "name": "My Folder",
    "url": "http://my-site.com/folder/1"
  },
  "url": "http://my-site.com/file/2"
}
```

Comment: Also asked on the mailing list [public-vocabs](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/): [Modeling question: folders (directories) and files](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-vocabs/2015Mar/0036.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might wanna consider the [Nepomuk File Ontology (NFO)](http://www.semanticdesktop.org/ontologies/2007/03/22/nfo/) instead.

Comment: Link is dead, seems like the project is dead.